# Using sizeof a Managed Structure in C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged, managed, sizeof

I am trying to port C++ code to C#. The code is meant to register a window class using `RegisterClassEx`.

The C++ code has an object `WNDCLASSEX wcex`. Object `wcex` has a property

```
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
```

In C#, I have defined the structure as

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WNDCLASSEX
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint style;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public PlatformInvokeGDI32.WNDPROC lpfnWndProc;
        public int cbClsExtra;
        public int cbWndExtra;
        public IntPtr hInstance;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public IntPtr hCursor;
        public IntPtr hbrBackground;
        public string lpszMenuName;
        public string lpszClassName;
        public IntPtr hIconSm;
    }
```

I have tried to get the size using

```
wcex.cbSize = (uint)sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
```

The function containing this stament is declared as

```
unsafe private void
```

I hoped the `unsafe` would make the statment work. However, I get this error in the IDE:

`Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('CaptureScreen.PlatformInvokeGDI32.WNDCLASSEX')`

Can I make the structure into an unmanaged structure? If so, how?
Is there a way to use sizeof without making the structure unmanaged?
Is there a .NET version of sizeof that would work?

Comment: Just to be sure.. you know that using Win32 API to create windows can be done a million times more easily with Windows Forms, the C#/.NET equivalent?

Comment: I do. My project is just supposed to help me learn about the Win32 API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Marshal.SizeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using  `wcex.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PlatformInvokeUSER32.WNDCLASSEX));`

Comment: Things change over time, and now MS recommends the generic form of this method, e.g. `(uint)Marshal.SizeOf<Win32.WNDCLASSEX>();`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netcore-3.1